# RegionCentroid issue

Tags: regions, geometry

This example shows an unexpected result from RegionCentroid:

```
object = 
  Polygon[
    {{20000, 200000}, {20000.1, 200000.2}, {20000.3, 200000.2}, {20000., 200000.}}];
point = Point[RegionCentroid[object]];
Show[Graphics[{object, Red, PointSize[.2], point}]]
```

[image: point should be inside object]

The RegionCentroid result should be inside the convex region.

When the object is translated to the origin the result is correct. Any idea for a general solution or workaround for arbitrary regions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is basically a numerics problem. If you were to do the computations exactly, there would be no problem.

```
obj =
  Polygon[
   {{20000, 200000}, {20000 + 1/10, 200000 + 2/10}, 
    {20000 + 3/10, 200000 + 2/10}, {20000, 200000}}];

pt = Point[RegionCentroid[obj]]
```

> ```
> Point[{300002/15, 3000002/15}]
> ```

```
Graphics[{obj, Red, AbsolutePointSize[8], pt}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: graphics]

Comment: yes, looks like an accuracy issue inside RegionCentroid. The translated object Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.3, 0.2}, {0, 0}}] works fine.

Comment: @Ali As another alternative to symbolic numbers you can also use arbitrary precision numbers via `20000.1\`50` (will give 50 digits of precision) or via `SetPrecision[20000.1,50]`. Just using machine precision numbers implicitly (by just writing `20000.1`) is considered intended behaviour and not an issue or bug. It's essentially a tradeoff between precision and computation time. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PrecisionAndAccuracyControl.html) for more info on this.

Comment: @Thies: Thanks, using `Polygon[SetPrecision[{...},20]]` indeed solves the issue in a general way.